# JS to autocalculate an input field based on other input values not working

Tags: javascript

Please I need help finding out why the calculation isn't working.
My console log does not show any error.

I want the third disabled input to just show an addition of the first two inputs. please see my code below. Is there something i am not including or adding?

```js
var yearlyMB = document.getElementById('yearlyMB').value;
var yearlyDB = document.getElementById('yearlyDB').value;

document.getElementById('totalBudget').value = yearlyMB + yearlyDB;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin-top: 200px;*/
}

.block-title {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block-answer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-title">Yearly Marketing Budget</div>
  <input type="text" class="block-answer" id="yearlyMB">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-title">Yearly Donation Budget</div>
  <input type="text" class="block-answer" id="yearlyDB">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-title">Total Budget</div>
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" class="block-answer" id="totalBudget">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most of the elements in place, but your code currently only runs once when the page is first loaded.

In order to constantly update the value in the 'totals' input you need to add listeners to your inputs watching for changes. See: [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

You also need to account for the fact that input values are always strings, the snippet below uses the [unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator to convert the input values to numbers before adding them together. If you don't do this you will simply concatenate the two strings.

```js
const yearlyMB = document.getElementById('yearlyMB');
const yearlyDB = document.getElementById('yearlyDB');
const totalBudget = document.getElementById('totalBudget');

function updateTotalBudget() {
  totalBudget.value = +yearlyMB.value + +yearlyDB.value;
}

[yearlyMB, yearlyDB].forEach(input =>
  input.addEventListener('input', updateTotalBudget));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin-top: 200px;*/
}

.block-title {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block-answer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-title">Yearly Marketing Budget</div>
  <input type="text" class="block-answer" id="yearlyMB">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-title">Yearly Donation Budget</div>
  <input type="text" class="block-answer" id="yearlyDB">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-title">Total Budget</div>
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" class="block-answer" id="totalBudget">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @pilchard. That was very helpful. I guess I still have a lot to learn in JS

Comment: No worries, just keep at it your code is looking fine.

Comment: Hi @pilchard, please how do i add the listener to a calculation that requires just one constant/var in the equation? eg if the equation at the end is function updateTotalBudget() {
  totalBudget.value = +yearlyMB.value / 12;
}

Comment: You would just need to add a listener for input on the `yearlyMB` input then, and adjust your function as you showed. `yearlyMB.addEventListener('input', updateTotalBudget));`